# Probability riddle that should be "easy"

Tags: probability

Given an 8x8 chess board, its squares are colored either white or black randomly. If X is the number of adjacent squares of the same color (vertically or orizontally, not diagonally), what is its expected value?
This should be an easy question, probably solved with an easy trick, but I thought about it for 2 days and couldn't make it

Comment: What do you mean by the expected value of adjacent squares? Are there values assigned to each square?

Comment: *number of adjacent squares, sorry. I'll edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a pair of adjacent squares, whether they'll be count into $x$ has nothing to do with the color of any other square. The probability of being same color is $\frac12$. So its contribution to $x$ is $1\times\frac12+0\times\frac12=\frac12$.

There are totally $7\times8+7\times8=112$ pairs of adjacent squares. This could be counted by separately counting vertically or horizontally adjacent ones. So $$x=112\times\frac12=\fbox{56}.$$